# UIView filled with a grid of UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, grid, uibutton

I'm trying to make a simple grid of UIButtons in Interface Builder. This seems to work but every time I run the app on my iPad the constraints seem to mess up the grid and the buttons are not aligned anymore. I think the constraints aren't set up properly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would suggest using a UICollectionView for something like this.

Comment: @Boohoo Are these individual buttons or you have set autolayout on the whole 'View'?

Comment: @raurora I fixed it just by disabling Auto Layout, now the buttons don't resize but I made it so it shouldn't resize. Though I do think  this is bad practice, but anyway it works.

Comment: Yes, I do the same when Auto Layout messes around too much. Have you tried adding Auto Layout constraints programmatically? That's a lot of code, but it would make good sense.